# arranging icons on pre-defined, non-linear places

Tags: javascript

I'm struggling to find a solution in which I need to lay clickable PNG icons over a background image (as shown in picture). The arrangement of icons is pre-defined but arbitrary, and is not linear, so that placing the PNGs in a grid would be sub-optimal.
I tried using SVG circles inside a `<div>` above the BG image (assigned as CSS `background-image:`) and getting the coordinates of the circles and assigning the coordinates to the icons with:

```
function createImage (imgIndex)
  {

    let node = icon_template.cloneNode(true);
    let xy = imgCoordinate(imgIndex);
    node.removeAttribute('hidden');
    node.style.top = xy[1] + 'px';
    node.style.left = xy[0] + 'px';
    node.setAttribute('src',theImages[imgIndex]);
    node.setAttribute('onclick',`console.log(\`image number: ${imgIndex}\`)`);
    canvas.appendChild(node);
  }
```

but I have encountered two main issues:

-Making the SVG the same size as, and aligning to, the background image. I get very erratic results regardless of countless CSS parameter combinations.

-(possibly because of the above) The icons do follow the same pattern as the circles but seem to be offset to varying degrees.

My questions are:

- Is my original approach even a good idea?
- What would be the easiest, most reliable way to achieve what I'm after.
  Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it using inline  tags inside an SVG laid on top of the backround image, which contains the icons at the correct locations. Basically had to import the Backround image in Inkscape, draw placeholder circles at desired icon locations, and then replacing the SVG tags, using "find & replace":
<circle for <image
r=50 for nothing
cy & cx for y & x
etc. until it worked. then programatically adding all the functionality.
For some reason using <img instead if <image did not work.

```
<style>
.svg-container {
position: relative;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  padding-bottom: 100%; /* override this inline for aspect ratio other than square */
  display:block; overflow:hidden;
  text-align: center;
   visibility: visible;
   background-image:  url("backgroundImage.png");
   text-align: center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size:contain;

}
</style>

<svg class="mySvg" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 983 983" enable-background="new 0 0 983 983" xml:space="preserve" height="983" width="983">

  <a class="theLinks">
    <image id="image1" class="buttonImg" height="72" width="72" y="537" x="83" href="01.png" ></image>
  </a>
  <a class="theLinks">
    <image id="image2" class="buttonImg" height="72" width="72" y="76" x="850" href="02.png" ></image>
  </a>
  <a class="theLinks">
    <image id="image3" class="buttonImg" height="72" width="72" y="620.25" x="583.26" href="03.png" ></image>
  </a>
</svg>

<script>
"use strict"
let  imageOver =[
    '01-over.png',
    '02-over.png',
    '03-over.png',
    ]

let links = [
let subPages = [
  '1.html',
  '2.html',
  '3.html',
]

let images = document.getElementsByClassName("buttonImg");
let links = document.getElementsByClassName("theLinks");

//convert html collection to array, probably not necessary in this particular case. In more general cases, functionality of array is broader than HTMLcollection
let imagesArray = [];
let linksArray = [];
for (let i=0;i<images.length;i++)
{
      imagesArray[i] = images[i];
      linksArray[i] = links[i];
}

for (let i=0; i< images.length; i++)
  {
  imagesArray[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function() {return imagesArray[i].setAttribute('href', `${imageOver[i]}`)});
  imagesArray[i].addEventListener("mouseout", function() {return imagesArray[i].setAttribute('href', `${imageUp[i]}`)});
  linksArray[i].setAttribute('href', `${subPages[i]}`);
}

</script>
```